# window.close() does not execute

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a text-based game, and `window.close();` is what I use when the character dies. However, when the `window.close();` handler is used, it doesn't close the window and just completely skips the part, moving on to the other alerts/if else statements.

```
alert("Part 2 of game commencing.");
alert("For this part of the game, you can re-state your computer password.");

var password = prompt("Enter your new password now!");
var passwordConfirm = prompt("Confirm your password.");
if (passwordConfirm == password) {
    alert("Correct! Both passwords match.");
} else if (passwordConfirm != password) {
    alert("Both passwords do not match.");
    var newPassword = prompt("Let's try this again, retype the password you want.");
    var newPassword = password;
    var passwordConfirm = prompt("Confirm your password (don't screw it up this time     you fool)");
    if (passwordConfirm == password) {
        alert("Correct! Both passwords match.");
    } else if (passwordConfirm != password) {
        alert("Wrong. You've missed your chance at getting a new password. Just use rat_race.");
    }
}

alert("You're starting to feel hungry.");
alert("You look up where you could eat for the night.");

var roomService = prompt("Do you (a) get room service or (b) eat out?");
if (roomService == "a") {
    alert("You call room service, and you ask for spaghetti.");
    alert("After five minutes, your meal arrives. You eat it.");
} else if (roomService == "b") {
    alert("You leave your room, taking your room key with you.");
    var elevator = prompt("You enter the elevator. Do you take floor B, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5     (case sensitive)");
    switch (elevator) {
        case "B":
            alert("You head down to the garage.");
            break;
        case "1":
            alert("You go to floor 1 and the doors slide open. You realise you're on the wrong floor. You go back in, and you press on B.");
            break;
        case "2":
            alert("You go to floor 2 and the doors slide open. You realise you're on the wrong floor. You go back in, and you press on B.");
            break;
        case "3":
            alert("You go to floor 3 and the doors slide open. You realise you're on the wrong floor. You go back in, and you press on B.");
            break;
        case "4":
            alert("You go to floor 4 and the doors slide open. You realise you're on the wrong floor. You go back in, and you press on B.");
            break;
        case "5":
            alert("You go to floor 5 and the doors slide open. You realise you're on the wrong floor. You go back in, and you press on B.");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Enter a valid option next time! Skipping exercise.");
    }
    alert("The elevator doors slide open.");
    alert("You walk over to your car, and you drive out of the parking lot.");
    alert("You arrive at the restaurant.");
    alert("You make your order, eat, and go back to your room.");
}

alert("You're feeling sleepy. You go to bed.");
var wakeUp = prompt("You wake up. Do you (a) sleep in, or (b) get out of bed?");
if (wakeUp == "a") {
    alert("You wake up again.");
} else if (wakeUp == "n") {
    //DO NOTHING//
}

alert("You decide that before going in for your kill, you should do some reconnaissance         first.");
alert("You head down to the garage, and you climb into your car.");
alert("You head to the Trenton Air Force Base.");
alert("You realise it's probably going to be pretty tough to actually get INTO the   base.");

var enterBase = prompt("Do you (a) crash your car through the main gate and kill the     guard, or (b) pull out your old military ID and bullshit your way through?");
if (enterBase == "a") {
    alert("You arrive at the base. You put the pedal to the metal, and you crash    through the fence.");
    alert("You swing open the door of your car and you shoot the guard in the head.");
    var killPeople = prompt("You're faced with a choice: you can either (a) get out of     the car and start shooting, or (b) drive past the 5 or more soldiers that are getting ready  to kill you.");
    if (killPeople == "a") {
        alert("The minute you step out of the car you are shredded by machine gun fire.");
        alert("You have died! Restart game.");
        window.close();
    } else if (killPeople == "b") {
        alert("You slam on the gas pedal and barely evade the machine gun fire.");
        alert("You make a U-turn and you get out of the base");
        alert("You can see a trail of police cars behind you as you try and get to  the country roads.");
        var shootCops = prompt("Do you (a) put your hand out the window and try and shoot some of them down or (b) stay focused and keep driving?");
        if (shootCops == "a") {
            alert("While trying to fit your arm out the window, you lose control of the car and you swerve into a tree.");
            alert("You have died! Restart game.");
            window.close();
        } else if (shootCops == "b") {
            //DO NOTHING//
        }
        alert("The police cars keep getting closer and close...");
        alert("You keep on looking back, and eventually, you lose control of the car and you crash into a tree.");
        alert("You have died! Restart game.");
        window.close();
    }
} else if (enterBase == "b") {
    alert("You slowly drive up to the fence, and the security guard comes to greet   you.");
    alert("You hand him your ID, he nods and opens the fence.");
}

alert("You feel like that was a little too easy. But none the less, you find barrack  212, and you then locate the admin he works in.");
alert("You spot him through the window, and you retreat to your car so that you can  follow him home.");
alert("Surely enough, after several hours, he goes on his lunch break.");

var followHim = prompt("You know he'll be back shortly. Do you (a) still follow him,  just to be sure, or (b) stay there and watch dumb videos on your phone.");
if (followHim == "a") {
    alert("You rev your engine, and slowly follow him to his vehicle. You keep     following him around, and he stops at subway for a meal.");
    alert("You follow him back to the admin, where he returns to his work.");
} else if (followHim == "b") {
    alert("You stay where you are.");
    alert("After half an hour, he returns but this time with a coffee in hand.");
}

alert("You wait a few more hours, and he leaves the admin with his bag. He's done work    for the day.");
alert("You follow him home.");
alert("You write down his address, and you head back to the hotel.");
alert("You find yourself in the hotel parking garage.");
```

Comment: Please remove all unnecessary information from your example (I doubt `roomService` is needed to understand your problem or help you). I'm also not sure what you mean by "window.close() handler". Did you install a listener for the close event?

Comment: Personally I think this solution would be better if you wrote the item to a `Div` / `Span` element rather than using an intrusive `alert` each time. IMO.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.close

Under **Description**:

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened
>   by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console:
>   Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can't use `window.open` if the window hasn't been opened by a script. One way to get around this is by using

```
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();
```

This will bypass the requirement in some browsers, it works in chrome but I haven't tried others.

I do recommend rethinking this though. Writing to a div / some sort of text box would be much easier for a user.

Comment: +1 for a cool find. Works in IE (9 at least) Chrome and Safari. No dice in Firefox.